# how to run 'EXEC dbms_stats.init_package()' using cx_Oracle

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I tried :
code :

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('xyz/xyz@xyz:1521/orcl')             
cur = conn.cursor()  
query = 'EXEC dbms_stats.init_package\(\)'                                     
cur.execute(query)
```

also

```
query = 'EXEC dbms_stats.init_package()'                                     
cur.execute(query)
```

for both try I get following error:

Error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statemen`t

can you please tell the correct way to run this SQL command

Comment: Maybe you should try ending the statement with `;`?

Comment: when ran through sqlcmd it shows that its a PL/SQL procedure

Comment: You are correct ignore my previous comment about the `()`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to execute `init_package()`?

Comment: I am trying to run DOTS on oracle 12c for that I need it.

Comment: As in www.serviceobjects.com? Do you have more info? The procedure is undocumented and nearly a googlebomb, even support.oracle.com has nearly no entries about it...

Comment: I am not sure about serviceobjects.com but I refer http://ltp.sourceforge.net/documentation/how-to/dots.php. If you have any particular query let me know I'll see if I can help

Answer (score 2):

`EXEC` is an sqlplus command, use `BEGIN..END` instead

```
proc='''BEGIN
 dbms_stats.init_package();
 END;'''
cur.execute(proc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call a stored procedure with `callproc`.

```
cur.callproc("DBMS_STATS.INIT_PACKAGE")
```

Details are [here](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.callproc)